# how to convert shamsi date to Gregorian with carbon in laravel

Tags: laravel

I found out that I have to use the carbon method to convert Jalali date to Gregorian and I found the conversion method with the following two lines that converts the TaskDate value from Jalali to Gregorian to insert in the table.

```
public function store(taskRequestStore $request,TaskService $service)
    {
        
        $request->TaskDate = CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($request->TaskDate, true);
        $request->TaskDate = CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->TaskDate)->format('Y-m-d');


        $attributes = $request->all(['Caption','TaskDsc',
                                    'office_id','TaskDate','Type','Priority_id',
                                    'Taskfile','StartDate','EndDate','Deadline',
                                    'Commander_id','OtherOffices','Status_id'
                                    ]);
                    
        $office = $service->create($attributes)->tosql();
        dd($office);
        return redirect()->back()->with(['create'=>'date Saved']);
    }
```

But I have already written my own store process in the controller as abow.
in blade:

```
<div class="col-3" style="float: right;display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
     <div class="col-auto p-2">
           {!! Form::label('TaskDate', 'TaskDate', ['class'=>'col-form-labels']) !!}
     </div>
 <div class="col-auto p-2 col-5"  style="float: right;">
  @error('TaskDate')
        <h6 class="text-danger text-center err-message">{{$message}}</h6>
  @enderror
</div>
</div>
```

How can I enter the value of TaskDate in the statement request->all in controller? Maybe I should do this somewhere else, like inside the blade or the model, but how do you do it?